# How to scrape through Google Scholar to generate lists based on keywords?

Tags: python, web-crawler, google-scholar

I want to generate lists that constantly update with the latest scientific publications from scholar.google.com. I have some terms that have to be constantly crawled and once those keywords are found in any new publication, it has to be added to the list.

How do I develop such an algorithm without the need to have NLP knowledge? Which libraries should be used?

I am rather new to programming with Python and I am looking for a simple approach to address this issue. Many thanks for any input.

Comment: My comment was based on misunderstanding the goal, but it's too late to edit so I'm deleting it so it doesn't cause confusion.